# Получить текст из названия раздела родителя нажатой кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Есть 2 раздела с 2 кнопками, при нажатии на каждую, нужно записывать ее в переменную, в соответствии тем, чтобы кнопка 1 получала заголовок из раздела 1 и тд.

```
<section>
<h1 class="sect__title">Заголовок раздела1</h1>
<p>
<ol>
<li>Элемент 1</li>
<li>Элемент 2</li>
<li>Элемент 3</li>
</ol>
<b>Стоимость <span class="price" id="price1">1000</span>руб.</b><br>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">tests
<button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Перейти</button>
</div>
</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h1 class="sect__title">Заголовок раздела2</h1>
    <p>
    <ol>
        <li>Элемент 4</li>
        <li>Элемент 5</li>
        <li>Элемент 6</li>
    </ol>
    <b>Стоимость <span class="price" id="price2">2000</span>руб.</b><br>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">tests
        <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"   data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Перейти</button>
    </div>
    </p>
</section>
```

я попытался сделать так, но у меня не получается:

```
var exampleModal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

var button = event.relatedTarget
var test = $(button).closest('.sect__title').text()
console.log(test)
```

И еще так пытался:

```
var test = $(button).parents().find('h1').text();
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const test = $('#button1').closest('section').find('.sect__title').text();
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<h1 class="sect__title">Заголовок раздела1</h1>
<p>
<ol>
<li>Элемент 1</li>
<li>Элемент 2</li>
<li>Элемент 3</li>
</ol>
<b>Стоимость <span class="price" id="price1">1000</span>руб.</b><br>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">tests
<button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Перейти</button>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас !